# use std::transform_reduce to compute complex expression

Tags: c++, c++17

I have the following:

```
std::vector<double> Coefficients;
std::vector<double> Functions;
std::vector<std::vector<double>> Polynomials;
```

given some inputs `std::vector<double> X` I want to evaluate the following `c1 * f1((x1^p1) * (x2^p2) * ...) + c2 * f2(...` with **c** being a value in `Coefficients`, **f** in `Functions` and **p** in `Polynomials`.

As an example:

```
Coefficients = {2, -4};
Functions = {sin, cos};
Polynomials = {{4, 3}, {2, 5}};
```

would have to compute:

```
2 * sin(x1^4 * x2^3) - 4 * cos(x1^2 * x2^5)
```

I found out about `std::transform_reduce` and it seems great because I can do the entire thing efficiently in one line, but I can't figure out the correct way to do it because of the number of encapsulated operations I have to perform. Can someone help me out with figuring it out?

I am thinking something like:

```
std::transform_reduce(
                    std::execution::par,
                    Coefficients.begin(), Coefficients.end(), Functions.begin(), 0.0,
                    std::plus<>(),
                    [&](double c, auto f) {
                        return c * f(std::transform_reduce(  // <-- transform reduce again for the polynomial inside the function and then again for (x^p)?
```

Comment: What values are `p1`, `p2` etc exatly? Your polynomials is a vector of vectors, I'm not sure what indices are needed when. I assume the first nested polynomial (inside `Functions[0]`) uses successive values from `Polynomials[0]`?

Comment: @perivesta I think some odd edit changed what I had originally meant to write for some reason. I've updated the post with an example

Comment: I see. In that case, the problem is that you need a different element of `Polynomials` for each application of the lambda in the outer `transform_reduce` but you can only pass two containers to the algorithm (`Coefficients` and `Functions` in your case).

Comment: I can only see this working if you pass an index sequence instead and manually get the correct elements from the containers using the index. But at that point, a nested loop is probably a lot clearer to read

Comment: Alternatively, you could change your data structures to have a struct with a single coefficient, function and vec of polynomial as members and then transform_reduce over a vector of those structs

Comment: I'd rather not change the data structure. Maybe a traditional loop is my only option I guess.

Comment: Doing this kind of calculation will become a lot easier in C++20/23 using ranges but I think it's not quite there yet for this example (`ranges::zip_view` comes to mind)

Comment: I'd be willing to use c++20, I'll have a look at `zip_view`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not using `ranges` you have to create an iterator for the polynomials vector and manually advance it inside outer `transform_reduce`. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/zjzaf5rTn

```cpp
#include <execution>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector vc = {   2.,  -4. };
    std::vector vf = { &sin, &cos };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vvp = { {4., 3.}, {2., 5.} };
    std::vector vx = {  42.,  69. };

    auto vpi = vvp.begin();
    auto res = std::transform_reduce(
        std::execution::par,
        vc.begin(), vc.end(),
        vf.begin(), 
        0.,
        std::plus(),
        [&](double c, auto f)
        {
            auto vp = *vpi++;
            return c * f(std::transform_reduce(
                std::execution::par,
                vx.begin(),
                vx.end(),
                vp.end(),
                0,
                &pow,
                std::multiplies()
            ));
        }
    );
}
```

**UPDATE**

With `ranges` you can zip the coefficient and function vectors together and won't need to roll your own iterator. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/EvzxbErMd

```cpp
#include <execution>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{

    std::vector vc = {   2.,  -4. };
    std::vector vf = { &sin, &cos };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vvp = { {4., 3.}, {2., 5.} };
    std::vector vx = {  42.,  69. };

    auto vcf = std::views::zip(vc, vf);

    auto res = std::transform_reduce(
        std::execution::par,
        vcf.begin(), vcf.end(),
        vvp.begin(), 
        0.,
        std::plus(),
        [&](auto cf, auto vp)
        {
            auto& [c, f] = cf;
            return c * f(std::transform_reduce(
                std::execution::par,
                vx.begin(),
                vx.end(),
                vp.end(),
                0,
                &pow,
                std::multiplies()
            ));
        }
    );
}
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

Using just the `ranges` library you can do this, which IMHO is the most readable version but does not support parallel execution. See here: https://godbolt.org/z/55zWWGE6s

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

inline constexpr auto reduce = std::ranges::fold_left;

int main()
{
    std::vector vc = {   2.,  -4. };
    std::vector vf = { &sin, &cos };
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> vvp = { {4., 3.}, {2., 5.} };
    std::vector vx = {  42.,  69. };

    auto res = reduce(
        std::views::zip_transform(
            [&](auto c, auto f, auto vp) {
                return c * f( reduce(std::views::zip_transform(pow, vx, vp), 1, std::multiplies()) );
            },
            vc, vf, vvp
        ),
        0, std::plus()
    );
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would this change if I were to use ranges?

Comment: I see, so that explains how range would simplify it a bit

Comment: @dearn44 yep, ranges are great. If you don't care about parallel execution, I think there is even a cleaner way of doing it with just ranges. Ranges don't have (yet?) parallel version of their algos.

Comment: you mean remove transform_reduce all together?

Comment: Yes... at least one of them... I will try to add another example in a minute

Comment: @dearn44 I've added another version